# Android Emulator error- Unfortunately app has stopped working

Tags: android, android-emulator

I was trying to run an example from the tutorial in Android-hive.

The example is AndroidBuildMusicPlayer
I successfully Launch the emulator with the app but when i click on the app icon in the emulator it gives me this error,

"Unfortunately app has stop working"

In CONSOLE:

```
[2014-08-31 19:55:25 - AndroidBuildingMusicPlayer] Dx     
trouble writing output: already prepared    
[2014-08-31 19:55:26 - AndroidBuildingMusicPlayer] ------------------------------    
[2014-08-31 19:55:26 - AndroidBuildingMusicPlayer] Android Launch!    
[2014-08-31 19:55:26 - AndroidBuildingMusicPlayer] adb is running normally.    
[2014-08-31 19:55:26 - AndroidBuildingMusicPlayer] Performing     com.androidhive.musicplayer.AndroidBuildingMusicPlayerActivity activity launch    
[2014-08-31 19:55:26 - AndroidBuildingMusicPlayer] Automatic Target Mode: launching new     emulator with compatible AVD 'Test'    
[2014-08-31 19:55:26 - AndroidBuildingMusicPlayer] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Test'    
[2014-08-31 19:56:39 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005    
[2014-08-31 19:56:39 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB    
[2014-08-31 19:56:39 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB    
[2014-08-31 19:56:39 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB    
[2014-08-31 19:56:39 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB    
[2014-08-31 19:56:39 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB    
[2014-08-31 19:56:39 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES     emulation, using software renderer.    
[2014-08-31 19:56:39 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB    
[2014-08-31 19:56:39 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB    
[2014-08-31 19:56:39 - Emulator] could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB    
[2014-08-31 19:56:39 - Emulator] Warning: No DNS servers found
```

Comment: paste your logcat after Warning: NO DNS servers found

Comment: It is not an emulator error. The error is in the code.

Answer (score 0):

There are some things you can try to fix this error(either one of them could fix the issue)

1. Increase the RAM for your emulator `Eclipse->Window->Android Virtual Device Manager->From the list of emulator, choose your emulator->Click on Edit->And Check Memory Option-> here Increase your Emulator RAM Size`. Advised to avoid allocating above 850MB as that might make your emulator stall. Restart your emulator and try again
2. Update intel graphics drivers: http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect/graphics (access via Internet Exporer)
3. Add SDK directory to PATH environment
4. Select 'use Host GPU" on your AVD configuration